# Must one state min/max values in addition to mean(+-std) when writing a publication?

Tags: publications

Is it 'a must' to state min/max values in addition to mean(+-std) when writing a publication?

Comment: I think we need more context about your field to provide a usable answer. In general, look at other publications in your field to learn about the customs.

Comment: The field is medical imaging. To be more concrete, it is related to cardiac segmentation and distance error between obtained 3d meshes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, SD and min/max are not bound to be reported together.

If the variable is *normally distributed*, -3SD and 3SD will include about 99.7% of the readings, indirectly giving an approximate value for minimum and maximum.

A concerning bad habit is reporting mean and SD without carefully checking if the distribution is approximately normal. For instance, if the variable is highly skewed (long tailed to either end,) then that interesting feature of -3SD and 3SD will disappear. In those cases, reporting median and inter-quartile range may be better if *you want to describe the central tendency*.

Reporting minimum and maximum has its merit if you wish to highlight the presence or absence of extreme values. In most of the analytical scenarios, min and max don't share as much spot light as mean; whether to report them is really context-specific.

There are a couple situations in which reporting min and max may be helpful:

1. You reported mean and SD already, but the variable is not normally distributed. (or alternately, report non-parametric summary such as median.)
2. You use a measurement tool that is rather unfamiliar to the readers. For instance, you developed a life quality scale and the mean and SD of the sample is 17.2 (+/- 3.6)... but out of what range? In that case, reporting both sample min/max (the min/max you actually observed) and possible min/max (the min/max score the instrument can actually give) will be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not a universal "must."

The statistics you should report in your publication depend on conventions in your discipline, the kind of data you are describing, your experimental methodology, and many, many other factors.

Consult your advisor and/or similar publications in your discipline to find out more about what's expected for the kind of research *you* are doing.